# Static folders structure in Django 1.4?

Tags: python, django, convention, directory-structure, django-1.4

This is the new project structure (from the Django 1.4 release notes).

```
myproject
|-- manage.py
|-- myproject
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- settings.py
|   |-- urls.py
|   `-- wsgi.py
`-- polls
    |-- __init__.py
    |-- models.py
    |-- tests.py
    `-- views.py
```

What I am not sure about is whether I should point STATIC_ROOT to

`myproject/myproject/static/` (together with settings.py, urls.py...)

**OR**

The top-level directory `myproject/static` (next to myproject, myapp1, myapp2)?

Comment: I don't know what the "official" word is, but I think the top level directory makes more sense.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`STATIC_ROOT` is not related to Python importing, so it totally depends on you. Normally, `myproject/static/`, thus `os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'static/')` in settings, is easier.

*update* as San4ez suggested, and notes inside settings.py

```
# Absolute path to the directory static files should be collected to.  
# Don't put anything in this directory yourself; store your static files  
# in apps' "static/" subdirectories and in STATICFILES_DIRS.  
# Example: "/home/media/media.lawrence.com/static/"
```

Better to put static files of the `poll` app into `poll/static/`, according to your structure.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with @okm that `myproject/static/` is a good place for static, but also you can store images, css and js inside your app in `myproject/polls/media`. Than you have to configure `django.contrib.staticfiles` app and copy static from `media` to STATIC_ROOT with command

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

The advantage of this approach that this allows you to spread your app with static and your app can be used freely in other projects

Comment: css, js, and images should all be subfolders in myproject/myproject/static, as well as myproject/poll/static. Using a folder named `media` is dangerous because it conflicts with the folder name typically used in django for images and other files uploaded by users. It's also a folder used by admin static files (after collectstatic). Collect static will indeed gather them up for a production server to then serve them from a central folder (usually outside your myproject folder structure, like /var/www/www.mysite.com/static).

Answer (score 1):

`STATIC_ROOT` is just a file path where the `staticfiles` contrib app will collect and deposit all static files. It is a location to collect items, that's all. The key thing is that this location is **temporary storage** and is used mainly when packaging your app for deployment.

The `staticfiles` app searches for items to collect from any directory called `static` in any apps that are listed in `INSTALLED_APPS` and in addition any extra file path locations listed in `STATICFILES_DIRS`.

For my projects I create a `deploy` directory in which I create a `www` folder that I use for static files, and various other files used only when deploying.  This directory is at the top level of the project.

You can point the variable to any location to which your user has write permissions, it doesn't need to be in the project directory.